# Clickable v-menu open on hover

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

Vuetify `v-menu` has `open-on-hover` property.

Using this, user can use menus using hover instead of clicking.

This hover menu close when itself clicked.

I want to set menu which have optional hidden area.

So, i need a hover menu can be clicked without closing.

Is there any way to do this?

thank you in advance.

this is my sample code.

```
<v-menu open-on-hover>
  <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
    <span>hover menu</span> 
  </template>
<!-- v-menu content -->
  <v-card>
    <v-btn @click="hiddenarea = true">open</v-btn>
<!-- hiddenarea -->     
    <span v-if="hiddenarea">Here is hidden area</span>
  </v-card>
</v-menu>
```

[Menu Component  -Vuetify.js](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/menus/#hover)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `close-on-content-click` for that

```
<v-menu open-on-hover :close-on-content-click="false">
```